# Why doesn't Đ get flattened to D when Removing Accents/Diacritics

Tags: c#, .net, string, diacritics

I'm using this method to remove accents from my strings:

```
static string RemoveAccents(string input)
{
    string normalized = input.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in normalized)
    {
        if (char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) !=
        UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            builder.Append(c);
        }
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

but this method leaves đ as đ and doesn't change it to d, even though d is its base char.
you can try it with this input string "æøåáâăäĺćçčéęëěíîďđńňóôőöřůúűüýţ"

What's so special in letter đ?

Comment: Could you show rewrite the string literal in the form "\uxxxx" etc? That will make it easier to repro without worrying about combining characters etc.

Comment: Is that a Turkish (or other east European character)?

Comment: @jon so how exactly do i do that?

Comment: It looks like an Eth to me, which is a letter in its own right.

Comment: Hi @MladenPrajdic, I also just stumbled upon the same problem :(. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer for *why* it doesn't work is that the statement that "d is its base char" is false. U+0111 (LATIN SMALL LETTER D WITH STROKE) has Unicode category "Letter, Lowercase" and has no decomposition mapping (i.e., it doesn't decompose to "d" followed by a combining mark).

`"đ".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)` simply returns `"đ"`, which is not stripped out by the loop because it is not a non-spacing mark.

A similar issue will exist for "ø" and other letters for which Unicode provides no decomposition mapping. (And if you're trying to find the "best" ASCII character to represent a Unicode letter, this  approach won't work at all for Cyrillic, Greek, Chinese or other non-Latin alphabets; you'll also run into problems if you wanted to transliterate "ß" into "ss", for example. Using a library like [UnidecodeSharp](http://unidecode.codeplex.com/) may help.)

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit that I'm not sure why this works but it sure seems to

```
var str = "æøåáâăäĺćçčéęëěíîďđńňóôőöřůúűüýţ";
var noApostrophes = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes(str));
```

=> "aoaaaaalccceeeeiiddnnooooruuuuyt"

Comment: The "Cyrillic" encoding appears to have a small table of fallback characters that it will use when the input character doesn't appear in code page 1251; this feels like an abuse of that undocumented behavior. It also converts "ß" (and any other unrecognised character) to "?", which may be inappropriate (as is the conversion of 'æ' to 'a'). For (almost complete) Unicode transliteration, check out http://unidecode.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly a hack. How does Unidecode compare to Iconv //TRANSLIT?

Comment: I haven't tested Unidecode against iconv //TRANSLIT; I suggested Unidecode in this instance because it's a .NET library (so no P/Invoke is required to use it).

Answer (score 3):

"[D with stroke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%90)" (Wikipedia) is used in several languages, and appears to be considered a distinct letter in all of them -- and that is why it remains unchanged.

Comment: Also, eth in Old English mutated into "th" in English, while in Norwegian it turned into "d". Beyond a superficial similarity to capital d, it's completely different.

Comment: yeah but the same applies to č or ć which is also a distinct letter.

Comment: Specifically, Unicode defines no decomposition mapping for đ (while it does for č and å, which some other alphabets consider to be distinct letters).

Answer (score 0):

`string.Normalize(NormalizationForm)` is an easy way to remove 'real' diacricits ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)) but many letters you may want to convert are not affected by this.

I had simmilar problems with Ð & ð (letter [Eth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eth)), đ, Æ & æ. To convert them into ANSI (Latin) use Unicode-conversion instead!

```
    private static char[] ConvertUnicodeStringToSpecificEncoding(string input, int resultEncodingCode)
    {
        System.Text.Encoding unicodeEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
        System.Text.Encoding specificEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(resultEncodingCode);

        byte[] convertedBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(unicodeEncoding, specificEncoding, unicodeEncoding.GetBytes(input));
        char[] convertedChars = new char[specificEncoding.GetCharCount(convertedBytes, 0, convertedBytes.Length)];
        specificEncoding.GetChars(convertedBytes, 0, convertedBytes.Length, convertedChars, 0);
        return convertedChars;
    }
```

Call this method with **multiple encoding** on the same string to create an intersection on the letters you want to have left.

List of encodings:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8

My solution looks like this

```
    // Encoding Types (int Codes) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8
    private static readonly char[] charactersToSkip = new char[] { 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'Ä', 'Ö', 'Ü' };
    private static readonly char[] specialCharsToSkip = new char[] { '^', '´', '`', '°', '!', '\'', '§', '$', '%', '&', '/', '(', ')', '=', '{', '[', ']', '}', '\\', '+', '-' };
    private static readonly char[] ambiguousCharsToSkip = new char[] { '?' };   // Chars which might be a result of encoding-conversion and have to be skipped beforehand.
    private static readonly int[] encodingsToRemoveDiacritics = new int[]
    {
        852,    // 852  ibm852  Central European (DOS)
        850,    // 850  ibm850  Western European (DOS)
        860,    // 860  IBM860  Portuguese (DOS)    

        /* Warning:
         * Only append encodings.
         * Changing sort order of encodings may result in malfunctioning.
         */ 
    };

    public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string inputString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString))
        {
            return inputString;
        }

        var resultStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char currentChar in inputString)
        {
            if (charactersToSkip.Contains(currentChar) || specialCharsToSkip.Contains(currentChar) || ambiguousCharsToSkip.Contains(currentChar))
            {
                resultStringBuilder.Append(currentChar);
                continue;
            }

            string normalizedString = currentChar.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
            foreach (char normalizedChar in normalizedString)
            {
                if (System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(normalizedChar) != System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                {
                    string convertedString = normalizedChar.ToString();
                    char[] convertedChars = null;

                    foreach (int encodingCode in encodingsToRemoveDiacritics)
                    {
                        convertedChars = ConvertUnicodeStringToSpecificEncoding(convertedString, encodingCode);

                        if (convertedChars.Contains('?') == false)
                        {
                            convertedString = new string(convertedChars);
                        }
                    }

                    resultStringBuilder.Append(convertedString);
                }
            }
        }

        return resultStringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

which creates following outputs

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxzy" -> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxzy"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" -> "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"1234567890" -> "1234567890"
"ß" -> "ß"
"ÄÖÜ" -> "ÄÖÜ"
"äöü" -> "äöü"
"!\"§$%&/()=?" -> "!\"§$%&/()=?"
"+-_~'*#" -> "+-_~'*#"
",.;:" -> ",.;:"
"µ" -> "u" // My -> u
"<>|" -> "<>|"
"´`^°" -> "´`^°"
"²" -> "2" // ² -> 2
"³" -> "3" // ³ -> 3
"{}" -> "{}"
"[]" -> "[]"
"\\" -> "\\"
"áàâã" -> "aaaa"
"ÁÀÂÅ" -> "AAAA"
"éèêę" -> "eeee"
"ÉÈÊĚ" -> "EEEE"
"íìîï" -> "iiii"
"ÍÌÎ" -> "III"
"óòôõ" -> "oooo"
"ÓÒÔŌ" -> "OOOO"
"úùû" -> "uuu"
"ÚÙÛ" -> "UUU"
"ÇĆĈČĊ" -> "CCCCC"
"çćĉčċ" -> "ccccc"
"Ñ" -> "N"
"Æ" -> "A"
"æ" -> "a"
"ýÿ" -> "yy"
"ĹĻĽ" -> "LLL"
"Ð" -> "D"
"đ" -> "d"
"ð" -> "d"
```

Answer (score -4):

this should work

```
    private static String RemoveDiacritics(string text)
    {
        String normalized = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < normalized.Length; i++)
        {
            Char c = normalized[i];
            if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                sb.Append(c);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This looks just like the original poster's code with FormKD changed to FormD (and minor stylistic changes). This won't work for the reasons given in other answers.

Comment: I've used FormD all the time until now and I wasn't aware of this problem, however as I can see (I just tested it) you are right. It doesn't work.