# How to convert utf8 signed string to unsigned string or char[] (in Java)

Tags: utf-8, char

I have a signed string like this: "Làm sao để chuyển chuổi có dấu về không dấu?"

And I want to translate it to string like this: "Lam sao de chuyen chuoi co dau ve khong dau?"

Please tell me the way to solve it in Java code. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String src = "Làm sao để chuyển chuổi có dấu về không dấu?";

    String dest = Normalizer.normalize(src, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    dest = dest.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");

    System.out.println(src);
    System.out.println(dest);
}
```

gives you

Làm sao để chuyển chuổi có dấu về không dấu?

Lam sao e chuyen chuoi co dau ve khong dau?

Comment: I just noticed that this doesn't quite give you what you require: để has been truncated to e.

Comment: It looks like the problem isn't that simple: there's a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362810/why-doesnt-get-flattened-to-d-when-removing-accents-diacritics

Comment: Yeah, that's not simple. But thanks a lot Jonathan, I'll follow your suggestion. :)

Comment: Would you please explain to me the meaning of this characters "[^\\p{ASCII}]" ?

Comment: replaceAll takes a regular expression, you can see details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum -- here is means to match anything that's not an ASCII character. The call to Normalizer.normalize decomposes characters with accents in to separate ASCII-character + Unicode combining accent-character, so when we filter out non-ASCII we have almost the string we want. Except đ doesn't seem to have an alternative ASCII+combining accent representation, so we end up removing it completely.